# PHP: formatting time Stackoverflow or Apple Mail-style

Tags: php, datetime, formatting, string-formatting

There is this [really nice function from the php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) that enables you to format time in a Facebook-style manner (e.g., `2 minutes ago`, `4 weeks ago`, or `3 years ago`).

However, I prefer the way Stackoverflow and Apple Mail does it which is generally as follows:

1. The current day is listed in `x seconds ago` or `x hours ago` or time (e.g, `4:35pm`).
2. Yesterday is listed as "Yesterday".
3. All days after that are listed by M/D/Y.

Has anyone adapted this php.net script to do this or might share a different script that accomplishes the same goal?

```
<?php 

  function nicetime($date)
 {
    if(empty($date)) {
      return "No date provided";
    }

$periods         = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
$lengths         = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

$now             = time();
$unix_date         = strtotime($date);

   // check validity of date
if(empty($unix_date)) {    
    return "Bad date";
}

// is it future date or past date
if($now > $unix_date) {    
    $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
    $tense         = "ago";

} else {
    $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
    $tense         = "from now";
}

for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
    $difference /= $lengths[$j];
}

$difference = round($difference);

if($difference != 1) {
    $periods[$j].= "s";
}

  return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
}

$date = "2009-03-04 17:45";
$result = nicetime($date); // 2 days ago

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried adapting that script?  Are your running into problems?

Comment: @MikeBrant yeah i'm running into problems, i'm not familiar with the bracket `{}` notation: `return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";`

Comment: The bracket notation is just another way to reference the variables inside double quotes.  I don't know why the author would use it around `$tense` and not around the other variables.  I personally, would keep it consistent ad do `return "{$difference} {$periods[$j]} {$tense}"` or `return $difference . ' ' . $periods[$j] . ' ' $tense;`

Comment: @MikeBrant -@Baylor, thanks for the tip on the brackets, now how to deconvolute the `for` loop: `for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
    $difference /= $lengths[$j];
}`

Comment: What is convoluted about that?  It is actually a pretty elegent way of determining which group of time (seconds, minutes, hours, days, etc.) is the best for displaying the time difference.

Comment: @MikeBrant one other question I can't google: what is the slash equals `/=` notation:  `$difference /= $lengths[$j];`?

Comment: `/=` is the same as `$var = $var / 2;`, just shorthand.

Comment: So the equation is this: `$difference = $difference/$lengths[$j];`?

Comment: @timpeterson That is correct.

Comment: @RobertK, i'm still confused on this `for` loop, so it sequential divides (current timestamp minus input `$date`)  by `"60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10"` ?

Comment: You solved my problem years back. but i'm up-voting now :) have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i answered my own question.

The key is to track how many rounds of division the `for` loop goes through until the quotient of the current time minus the input time, `$difference`, divided by `$j`th value of the `$lengths` array item is less than the `$j+1`th value of this array.

I track this by incrementing the variable `$i` (notice the `if/elseif/else` clause demonstrating each of the 3 points I mention above) in this modified version of `nicetime()`:

```
     ///http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php
  function nicetime($date)
 {
    if(empty($date)) {
      return "No date provided";
    }

$periods         = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
$lengths         = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

$now             = time();
$unix_date         = strtotime($date);

   // check validity of date
if(empty($unix_date)) {    
    return "Bad date";
}

// is it future date or past date
if($now > $unix_date) {    
    $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
    $tense         = "ago";

} else {
    $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
    $tense         = "from now";
}
$i=0;
for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
    $i++;
    $difference /= $lengths[$j];
}

$difference = round($difference);

if($difference != 1) {
    $periods[$j].= "s";
}

if($i<3){
    $day="$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
    return $day;
    //satisfies case #1 where time is listed as seconds, minutes, hours ago
}

elseif($i==3){
    $difference == 1 && $periods[$j]=='day' ? $day='yesterday':     
    $day="$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
    return $day;        
    //satisfies case #2 where time is listed as yesterday if not the current day

}
else{
    return $date;       
    // satisfies case #3 where date is listed as M/D/Y if greater than a week old
}   

}

echo "case#1: ".nicetime('2012-08-13 23:12:16');
echo "case#2: ".nicetime('2012-08-12 23:12:16');
echo "case#3: ".nicetime('2012-07-07 23:12:16');
```