# get timestamp from mysql database and get php to calculate time in days, hours, minutes?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: formatting time Stackoverflow or Apple Mail-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941888/php-formatting-time-stackoverflow-or-apple-mail-style)

Hi can someone please help me i am echoing out the timestamp in the mysql table but i want php to calculate the timestamp in days/hours/minutes.

Is this possible, im still new to php and mysql and am learning so could someone please guide me in the right direction or show me how this would be done. thank you

```
<? echo "{$news['date_added']}";?>
```

i want the output to be number of seconds: added 12 seconds ago or added 3 minutes ago or added 4 days ago or added 4 months ago

would i be right in thinking the script should look something like this:

```
function nicetime($date)
{
    if(empty($date)) {
        return "No date provided";
    }

    $periods         = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths         = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

    $now             = time();
    $unix_date         = strtotime($date);

       // check validity of date
    if(empty($unix_date)) {   
        return "Bad date";
    }

    // is it future date or past date
    if($now > $unix_date) {   
        $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
        $tense         = "ago";

    } else {
        $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
        $tense         = "from now";
    }

    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }

    $difference = round($difference);

    if($difference != 1) {
        $periods[$j].= "s";
    }

    return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
}

$date = "{$news['content']}";
$result = nicetime($date); // 2 days ago ?>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Yet another "hours ago" question. Did you search?

Comment: So now your question has changed entirely from it's original. Please, next time before posting questions, verify that your question is clear enough for people to answer correctly.

Comment: So now you're asking if _that_ answer is right?

Comment: no my question is the same i am wanting to show the mysql time stamp but out put the information as minutes, hours or days. how has my question changed even remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-02-03 19:13:00');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%h hours %i minutes');
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/priuP)

Reference

- [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Comment: thanks this works great, but do you know how i could take out the hours when the date value = less than 60 minutes? so at the moment if something was added 30 minutes ago it says added 0hours 30 minutes ago but i don't want the hours to appear if 0?

Comment: You can use str_replace to replace any values with zero in them: `str_replace('0 hours', '', $variable);`

Comment: ok and can i add a months string to this?

Comment: Yes. The dateinterval page tell you how to format it to your liking.

Comment: so i have put it all together with the srt_replace but the 0hours still shows?
<? str_replace('0 hours', '', $variable);
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime ($news['date_added']);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%h hours %i minutes');
?>

Comment: It would be easier to explain if you open a new question showing the code. Trying to do this in comments is kinda tough.

Comment: @Robert Taylor I have some code written that may help you if you do ask a new question. Just let meknow if you ask it. Post a link to it for me so i can find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `date()` function in the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d",$news['date_added']); ?>
```

Will print for example:

```
2013-02-04
```

Comment: You forgot the strtotime. You can't pass a raw timestamp to the date function - must be converted to unix time beforehand.

Comment: He says that he saves timestamp into the database. Which type, then?

Comment: That's true, and if he is saving the timestamp that way, then it's not "politically correct". Rather he should use UPDATE_TIMESTAMP natively in PHP or better, call the NOW() function if he'd rather update it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If your timestamp in MySQL table you can use **[FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)** function to get it in appropriate format.